# pyspark join with conditions for empty string

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark

I have three dataframes as below.

```
df_prod

Year  ID      Name   brand  Point 
2020  20903   Ken    KKK    2000
2019  12890   Matt   MMM    209
2017  346780  Nene   NNN    2000
2020  346780  Nene   NNN    6000

df_miss

Name    brand   point
Holy    HHH     345
Joshi   JJJ     900

df_sale

ID      Name  Year    brand   
126789  Holy  2010            
346780  Nene  2017    NNN     
346780  Nene  2020    NNN
```

I need to join df_sale depending upon the condition as below.
If "brand" is NOTNULL, then I need to join df_sale with df_prod on INNER join ON Year and Name.
If "brand" is NULL, then I need to join df_sale with df_miss based on Name.

Is it possible to have when condition during joins in pyspark? I could see some examples on scala but I am looking for pyspark implementation.

Pseudo code logic

```
if brand != null
   df_sale.join(df_prod, on=['Year', 'ID'], how='inner') and df_sale['Name'] = df_prod['Name'] & df_sale['point'] = df_prod['point']
   
elif brand == null
   df_sale.join(df_miss, on=['Name'], how='nner') and
   df_sale['point'] = df_prod['point']
```

Expected output:

```
ID      Name  Year    brand   point
126789  Holy  2010            345
346780  Nene  2017    NNN     2000
346780  Nene  2020    NNN     2000
```

Is it possible to do in pyspark or SQL. Please give some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you think about `IF ... ELSE ...` conditions in DataFrames (or for that matter, SQL tables), please be aware that these need to apply to the table as if you were traversing it row-by-row.

This leaves you with two options (please note that `f` denotes `pyspark.sql.functions`):

1. You split your `df_sale` table in two - `df_sale_brand_null` and `df_sale_brand` based on the `f.col("brand").isNull()` condition using something like `[input_df.filter(~fail_test), input_df.filter(fail_test)]`. Then you join with the relevant tables (`df_sales_brand_null` with `df_miss`) on desired columns, you handle misaligned columns and finally you `unionByName` the two joined tables.
2. You `union` the dataframes `df_miss` with `df_prod`, handling for the missing columns in `df_miss`. Then you join `df_sale` with the unioned table (aliased `a` and `b` respectively) on a conditional statement, such as `f.when(f.col("brand").isNotNull(), (f.col("a.Year") == f.col("b.Year")) & (f.col("a.ID") == f.col("b.ID")).otherwise(f.col("a.Name") == f.col("b.Name"))`. The output of `f.when(...).otherwise(...)` is a column and therefore your `join` statement will recognise it as a valid input to the `on=` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the logic. I shall try.